# ArrayList Adapter (for ListView) only displaying the first added item

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

**Edit3:** My own item list layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
/>
```

**Edit2:** Honestly, I might just make a for-loop that creates buttons for each file. This is way too much of a headache to be worth the time.

**Edit:** I'd like to emphasize the fact that I've copy+pasted my exact code into a new test app and it works fine. That might give you guys a clue.

After tons of debugging, I've narrowed down a problem. I'm trying to add items (files) to an ArrayList, then put that into an ArrayAdapter, and finally display the items in a ListView. The problem is that only the first added item is being displayed.

Here's how I was trying to do it:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.templateFilesList);

    ArrayList<String> templateList = new ArrayList<>();



    File myDir = getContext().getFilesDir();
    File[] templateFiles = myDir.listFiles();

    int length = templateFiles.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        templateList.add(templateFiles[i].getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            templateList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The templateFiles[] array properly gets the 8 files in Internal Storage (confirmed via logcat/debugger), but only the first item is displayed in the ListView. Here's a clearer look at the issue:

```
// If I replace the for loop with this:

    templateList.add(templateFiles[1].getName());
    templateList.add(templateFiles[0].getName());
```

Only templateFiles[1] is displayed. Similarly, if I do this:

```
    templateList.add(templateFiles[0].getName());
    templateList.add(templateFiles[1].getName());
```

Only templateFiles[0] is displayed. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.template_housing.MyTemplatesFrag"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_templates"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@color/Gold1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
/>

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/templateFilesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml code also?

Comment: Try to add some simple Strings ("a","b","c"...) in the list instead of templateFiles[i], and see if the problem is still exist.

Comment: Your code seem to be fine. I assume your `ListView` is populated properly but somehow only  the first item is visible. Please confirm by calling `getCount()` on your `ListView` instance after your `setAdapter()` call. If this is the case, please post the XML code of your layout.

Comment: Alright, xml posted. @Leo.Han - putting simple strings in still has the issue of only the first (in this case, "a") being shown.

Comment: getCount result is 8. That is correct, as I have 8 files in Internal Storage.

Comment: Check if  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 have match_parent or fill_parent as android:layout_height. If so change it with a fixed size or wrap_content

Comment: It's weird,Can you share your fully code on Github so that we can better review your code and run on our own phone.

Comment: I agree with @cristian mini , could you define your own item XML with height set to wrap content? In the new project, your minSdk and compileVersion versions are the exact same? Something might be wrong with Android's XML in a particular SDK version

Comment: @JorgeMendez - Both projects are the exact same. Min sdk of 17, compile version of 24. Wrote my own item XML, added to my original post as an edit. Height is set to wrap_content.

Comment: Could you try without the line, tools:context="com.template_housing.MyTemplatesFrag" ?

Comment: @I_A_Mok No difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the content of your adapter you should be calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` as well to make sure your adapter gets to know that your content did change

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` should be called if you update the dataset _after_ the adapter has been set. It's completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Please post your xml file

Comment: @JorgeMendez XML posted.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and ran it in Android Studio. It seems NO problem.

Here is my activity code(same xml code), the only difference is that I use an Activity, you may use a Fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.templateFilesList);
    ArrayList<String> templateList = new ArrayList<>();

    File myDir = getFilesDir();
    File[] templateFiles = myDir.listFiles();
    int length = templateFiles.length;

    //case 1: in my project, length is 1, show only one element, see case2.
//        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
//            templateList.add(templateFiles[i].getName());
//        }

    //case 2: try to add simple strings, 
    //because you said put simple strings in the list could cause the problem, too.
    templateList.add("a1");
    templateList.add("a2");
    templateList.add("a3");

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            templateList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
}
```

[image]

I shared my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/leoleohan/SO39050132).I strongly recommend you post your fully code on Github, let's review your code.

Comment: Yup, copying and pasting my exact code into a new Test App works perfectly. I'm so lost on this right now...I'll look at posting it to GitHub now

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to an array of Strings:

```
String [] templateListArray = templateList.toArray(new String[templateList.size()]);
```

and then do the assignment as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            templateListArray);
```

Hope this will fix it.

Comment: Same issue, it only displays the first item.

Comment: Try the updated one. And check what values the array adapter contains,

Comment: Same problem. The string array contains the right items when passed into the Array Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the simple list item 1 XML file too. This issue is not Java code related it has something to do with XML and size of elements. Try deleting that text view on top of the list view and your simple list item view should have `wrap content` as layout height.

And if you still want to use the textview you can use weight attribute. Give your textview a weight of 0 and the list view a weight of 1.

Comment: won't be an issue, because if single item is match [parent then others will still come via scroll down.

Comment: Oh I see :) But I'm pretty sure this is XML related. Just can't see what

Comment: Would making list views closing tag a self closing tag make a difference ?

Comment: you mean like this <ListView .....> </ListView> ?? <ListView .... /> both are ok :)

Comment: Same problem after deleting the text view.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that your array adapter is not setting properly and therefore it is not working properly, so try to replace your array adapter by below code and check if it is working,

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, templateList);
```

Comment: You can use this or getApplicationContext() any one

Comment: "this" and "getApplicationContext" get the whole statement underlined in red. Using getContext() instead doesn't error out, but the same original problem persists.